# Ad Banner Outside Of App

Tags: android, ads, banner-ads

I'm making an app whose sole functionality is to run a service in the background. It's not incidental like a messenger app it's literally the app's sole purpose.

I'd like to have an ad banner at the top of the user's screen while the service is running. I think this might be possible if I (unnecessarily) spawn a widget "chat bubble" as another app, Robotmon, does exactly this (the downside being that the ad is under the widget which causes there to be wasted space).

Every Google search I've made (and the documents) say nothing about this. I only find results discussing malware and apps that otherwise have no business spawning popups and whatnot. I plan to be upfront about the ad banner and know that it won't be a problem.

Comment: A background service is a background service, imagine if you had 10 similar services...they would all be deleted from my phone.

Comment: Mine controls your phone while you're AFK. It's not exactly a background service.